# How to use SSO login with MV3 in chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is there a way to implement SSO login in MV3 for chrome extension?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

add to manifest
`"permissions": [ "identity" ],`
add to popup
`

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, token =>
{
  if ( chrome.runtime.lastError || ! token ) {
    alert("SSO ended with an error: ${JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError)}")
    return
  }
signInWithCredential(auth, GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token))
    .then(res =>
    {
      console.log("signed in!")
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
      alert('SSO ended with an error: ${err}')
    })
})
```

`

try this >> https://medium.com/@elhardoum/implementing-firebase-auth-sso-with-google-in-chrome-extensions-with-manifest-v3-and-react-js-5946bca0ba19

The Chrome extension source code can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/elhardoum/firebase-auth-sso-mv3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question wasn't only about Google.